# sending a variable into a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I wanted to use an array in a thread but I don't know where to put it so that the new thread accepts it and uses it in the run method

My code so far is

```
    public void game (Button[] temp) {
        Thread check = new Thread(new startGame());
        check.start();
    }
    class startGame implements Runnable {
        startGame() {}
        public synchronized void run() {
            if (temp[0].getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor() == temp[1].getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor() )
            {
                temp[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                temp[1].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } 
        }
    }
```

I pretty sure I have to put `temp` inside `startGame()` but where in the startGame class do I put `temp` so that I can use it in the if statement?

Comment: You cannot call `setVisibility` from a background thread (or do anything  touching the UI). You need to post this as a runnable to a handler on the main thread (`Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); uiHandler.post(runnable...);`) or use `runOnUiThread(runnable)` from within an activity.

Comment: what are you trying to do actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing it inside your `startGame` class which should be named `StartGame`. Passing it in the constructor and setting a class variable to the value.

```
 public void game (Button[] temp) {
        Thread check = new Thread(new startGame(temp));
        check.start();
    }
    class startGame implements Runnable {
        private Button[] temp
        startGame(Button[] temp) {
            this.temp=temp;
        }
        public synchronized void run() {
            if (temp[0].getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor() == temp[1].getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor() )
            {
                temp[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                temp[1].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ug_ is correct.  Make it a class variable, set some locks if it's shared, and access it like any other class variable.

But as Ashton Engberg astutely pointed out in a comment, you cannot modify UI elements from outside the UI thread.